# Is it possible to get cryptocurrency historical prices from 1inch API?

Tags: python, web-scraping, cryptocurrency

I have been looking at the 1inch API, and it seems to me that it is mainly dedicated to performing transactions or swapping tokens. However, I am interested in getting historical prices of cryptocurrencies present on 1inch (DEX aggregator). Therefore, I was wondering if I could retrieve this information via the 1inch API?

Comment: you could get the historical price from coinmarketcap

Comment: Thanks galaxyan! 
In fact, I would prefer to get the historical prices from 1inch api to get closer to the "true" price since trades are getting on 1inch, instead of looking at the prices on coinmarketcap.